# regex matchall group id data

Tags: javascript, regex

the goal is with one pattern MatchAll find my strings and return all ids that contain my strings.

I need to capture multiple groups specific id with my strings

is big data: trucid="IDa" (string and size are random) trucid="IDb" (string and size are random b)...

my string can be anywhere in the (string random)

for my test I tried to catch the second id bbbbbbbbbb with 4000
my result is aaaaaaaaaa 4000 my pattern is not good...

test:

```js
var V_H='trucid="aaaaaaaaaa" tram 1000 l 11ala trucid="bbbbbbbbbb" tralala mm400011 tra1lala trucid="hajahjzabj" tra lam ba klal trucid="2ajah2zab2" ^ ^ #((6000 *=+ ...';

var regex2 = /trucid="([A-Z0-9]{10})"(?!trucid=")(?:.*?(4000|6000))/gmi;
   
var V_MatchAll = V_H.matchAll(regex2);                  

for (let found2 of V_MatchAll) {
   console.log('id:'+ found2[1]+'|find:'+found2[2]);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to get 2 capture groups, and match either 4000 or 6000, for the example string you can use:

```
\btrucid="([A-Z0-9]{10})"\D*([46]000)
```

The pattern matches:

- `\btrucid="` A word boundary to prevent a partial match, then match `trucid="`
- `([A-Z0-9]{10})` Capture group 1, match 10 times any of the listed ranges
- `"\D*` Match `"` and optional non digit chars
- `([46]000)` Capture group 2, match either 4000 or 6000

**Note** that you don't need the `/m` flag as there are no anchors in the pattern.

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/3s3LYA/1)

```js
const regex2 = /\btrucid="([A-Z0-9]{10})"\D*([46]000)/gi;
const V_H = 'trucid="aaaaaaaaaa" tram 1000 l 11ala trucid="bbbbbbbbbb" tralala mm400011 tra1lala trucid="hajahjzabj" tra lam ba klal trucid="2ajah2zab2" ^ ^ #((6000 *=+ ...';
const V_MatchAll = V_H.matchAll(regex2);

for (let found2 of V_MatchAll) {
  console.log('id:' + found2[1] + '|find:' + found2[2]);
}
```

To not cross matching trucid in between:

```
\btrucid="([A-Z0-9]{10})"(?:(?!trucid="[^"]*").)*([46]000)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/yOWb9x/1)

Comment: hi the string are randoms var V_H='trucid="aaaaaaaaaa" Im random I can be anything trucid="bbbbbbbbbb" Im randIm random4000Im random trucid="hajahjzabj" Im random trucid="2ajah2zab2" ^ ^ #((6000 *=+ ...'; result:"id:aaaaaaaaaa|find:4000"

Comment: @intercepte Like this? https://regex101.com/r/yOWb9x/1 `\btrucid="([A-Z0-9]{10})"(?:(?!trucid="[^"]*").)*([46]000)`

Comment: yes I think this is good.thank you The fourth bird

Comment: I think for a valid matching of the possible numbers the end-pattern of `([46]000)` needs to be *terminated* by `\D`. Otherwise any following digit like with `40001` or `60001` makes the entire pattern match as well.

Comment: @PeterSeliger I see this `mm400011` in the data wich would not match with `\D`

Comment: hi @PeterSeliger I use the second answer with (?!trucid="[^"]*").). Now I understand (?! it works exactly as I wanted.

Comment: @intercepte ... everything is fine, finally you've got the solution that works for you. Even better, you learned something from it.

Answer (score 1):

In case the OP wants to [capture just the value of any matching `id` pattern](https://regex101.com/r/puo9K2/1) a valid approach might look similar to the following example code ...

```js
const regXCapture = (/trucid="([^"]+)"\D+(?:4000|6000)\D/g);

const sampleText = `trucid="aaaaaaaaaa" tram1000lala trucid="bbbbbbbbbb" tralala4000  tralala trucid="hajahjzabj" tral6000 ambaklal
trucid="aaaaaaaaaa" tram6000lala trucid="bbbbbbbbbb" tralala40000  tralalatrucid="hajahjzabj" tral6000 ambaklal`;

console.log(
  [...sampleText.matchAll(regXCapture)].map(
    result => result[1]
  )
);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

And in case of capturing both values, the `id` and the matching / terminating `number` related ones, one might change the above approach slightly to [named captured groups](https://regex101.com/r/puo9K2/2) and to e.g. customizable numbers ...

```js
function extractIdAndNumberItems(str, numberList) {
  const regXCapture = RegExp(
    `trucid="(?<id>[^"]+)"\\D+(?<number>${ numberList.join('|') })\\D`,
    'g'
  );
  return [...str.matchAll(regXCapture)].map(
    // result => [result[1], result[2]]
    ({ groups }) => groups
  );  
}

const sampleText = `trucid="aaaaaaaaaa" tram1000lala trucid="bbbbbbbbbb" tralala4000  tralala trucid="hajahjzabj" tral6000 ambaklal
trucid="aaaaaaaaaa" tram6000lala trucid="bbbbbbbbbb" tralala40000  tralalatrucid="hajahjzabj" tral6000 ambaklal`;

console.log(
  extractIdAndNumberItems(sampleText, [4000, 6000])
);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: your code work but not resolve my problem. it's a bigdata the string is random. if I change sample more hard not work.  const sampleText = `trucid="aaaaaaaaaa" tram lala trucid="bbbbbbbbbb" tralala4000  tra trucid="oooooooooo" tra la  l #^^a ...`;